# How to deploy Asp.Net Core web app to Azure Managed Application

Tags: azure-managed-app

I want to create an Azure Managed Application with an App Service that hosts an Asp.Net Core web app that I've created.

Is it possible to deploy an Asp.Net core web application to an Azure Managed Application when the Customer deploy to its Azure Subscription?

I only found information about creating Azure resources, but not publishing anything to or manipulating any information on them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This doc page may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/reference-main-template-artifact

This shows how to deploy an Azure Function using `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`, but this should be similar for other Web App flavors:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package